# Even when flagged otherwise, Xcode still has issues with Non-ARC files in an ARC project

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

When building a project with a non-ARC framework, I specified the `-fno-objc-arc` flag for all its related files:

[image: flags correctly entered]

When I build, the issue navigator still puts up a fight with several ARC-related warnings:

[image: arc warnings]

The project still builds and runs correctly, it's just annoying to have these bugging me the entire time.

Is this an issue with Xcode or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just try Product → Clean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rebooting? Xcode can be a bit buggy and not see changes all the time. I get lots of problems if I rename files.